# Using BigQuery in DataGrip with JDBC

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery, datagrip

Has anyone been able to use the new JDBC drivers for BigQuery in JetBrains DataGrip?

I've followed the these steps

1. Created a driver in DataGrip with all the jar files
2. Created a database with a connection string with a service account file

The connection test says *successful*, but once I try to query something I receive an error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory
```

I've added the following files from the Simba ZIP into the DataGrip driver:

- GoogleBigQueryJDBC42.jar
- jackson-core-2.1.3.jar
- google-api-client-1.22.0.jar
- google-api-services-bigquery-v2-rev320-1.22.0.jar
- google-http-client-1.22.0.jar
- google-http-client-jackson2-1.22.0.jar
- google-oauth-client-1.22.0.jar

So I'm not sure what to do next. I tried changing their order in DataGrip but it didn't seem to make a different.

My connection string also looks OK I think:

```
jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;ProjectId=...;OAuthType=0;OAuthPvtKeyPath=...;OAuthServiceAcctEmail=...;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get this error when the driver JAR files are not referenced correctly in the tool. I have listed out the steps I used to connect to BigQuery via DataGrip.

- Add a new driver by adding all the JAR files from the zip. The correct class name should be selected from the "Class" drop down in this step.
- Add a new data source by selecting the newly created BigQuery JDBC driver. Provide the correct connection URL in this step.
- If the test connection succeeds, create a new query for the same datasource.
- Make sure your query uses the correct format "dataset.tablename" and is running on the data source you just tested.

Comment: The class drop down was indeed not set correctly. After that it still didn't work, but restarting DataGrip finally did. I can now query BigQuery from DataGrip. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For me replacing P12 with Json worked. But, cannot use DataGrip or in general JDBC to access BigQuery because of various query/incompatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

This video can be referred : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9l2c_aQPoQ&ab_channel=JetBrainsTV
to use the new simba jdbc drivers for BigQuery in JetBrains DataGrip. It covers all steps one by one for working setup.

Here is the blog which refers this video: https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2018/07/10/using-bigquery-from-intellij-based-ide/

Drivers can be downloaded at : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/providers/simba-drivers

Note: Make sure to go through comments on blog to authenticate without creating service account on gcp.

Hope this is helpful!